# Nginx does not serve the flask pages and shows the default static page

Tags: nginx, flask, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn, amazon-ec2

I have a flask app running with gunicorn and nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 using AWS EC2. I have deleted default site from /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. In those two folders, there is only one file: flasky - my nginx file as below:

```
server {
listen 80;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/flasky.sock;
}
```

When I enter the IP of the server in the browser, the default Nginx static page shows up. If I go to /auth/login, the correct page served by Flask shows up properly.

If the change the port from 80 to 8080, restart Nginx, enter http://ip-address:8080 then all Flask pages work well. I don't know how to fix this for port 80. Please help! Thanks!

UPDATE: I just found out that if I use the AWS Public DNS: http://ec2-50-112-125-180.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, it works. But if I use the corresponding Elastic IP: 50.112.125.180 it shows the nginx default page. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Just remove the default vhost its probably a conflict in load order because you don't have a `hostname` defined.

Comment: as I said, I already deleted default.

Comment: Can you please post your nginx.conf file. Sorry I mustn't have taken that in as I read. Please also ensure you have done an nginx reload

Comment: Thanks, Joe. But I think it's related to AWS EIP - it works fine if not used with EIP - don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Search your `nginx.conf` for the word `include`
maybe it's including other directories for config files.

Also, there may be other config blocks with

```
location /
```

that is superseding this section that also have `listen 80`.

Comment: Thanks， but my conf file only has the lines shown in my original post

Comment: Right, but the conf you pasted is from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Comment: But I was thinking the other includes, or location blocks  are in the main nginx.conf    at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf looks is as follows: https://gist.github.com/harrywang/3197f7726c3085ba481d . It includes /etc/nginx/conf.d/* but that folder is empty.